# Is it possible to cross the Wagan border by car?

Tags: india, borders, road-trips, pakistan, wagah

I was planning a trip by car when I found something a bit weird in [Google Maps](https://www.google.es/maps/dir/%D9%84%D8%A7%DB%81%D9%88%D8%B1+Lahore%E2%80%AD/Wagah,+Punjab,+India/@35.4227943,76.3185562,6z/data=!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x39190483e58107d9:0xc23abe6ccc7e2462!2m2!1d74.3571581!2d31.5546061!1m5!1m1!1s0x391912bcf27f495d:0x325315a52b19a1a9!2m2!1d74.574136!2d31.604757):if you try to cross from Lahore to India, it tells that you have to 6457 km detour.

Is it possible to cross this border driving? If not, is there another way to cross without having to make more than 6000 km?

Comment: Google maps often has disconnects on roads at international borders that you can in fact cross. These are pretty unpredictable but I've run into them on multiple occasions myself. - Which is not to say that you *can* cross. Only that Google might be right or it might be wrong.

Comment: You can click the menu icon, "Send Feedback" and then "Report a data problem" to tell Google about the problem.

Comment: Well, I don't know if that's a real "failure". May be you can't cross the border with your own private car. The unique answer here doesn't clarify this point :/

Answer (score 8):

There appear to be restrictions on the vehicles that are [allowed to cross the border at Wagah:](http://wikitravel.org/en/Wagah)

> Regular buses or taxis are not allowed into the no-man's land between the countries, so unless you're on one of the few deluxe international buses, you'll have to walk across the 500m between the border posts yourself. Porters -- blue coats for the Indians, green coats for the Pakistanis -- can carry your belongings for a few dollars. There is a taxi stand on the Indian side of the border and you can get a taxi from there. The Pakistan side taxi stand is about one kilometer away.

It's not clear to me whether private passenger vehicles (as opposed to buses & taxis) are allowed across, nor whether there are other border crossings that allow for private passenger vehicles.  However, Wagah also appears to be the [only crossing that is open for international travelers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_between_India_and_Pakistan#Delhi-Lahore_Bus), so if you're not from India or Pakistan, you'll definitely have to go the long way around.