# Is it possible to travel from India to Russia through Pakistan?

Tags: visas, passports, indian-citizens, overland, carnet-de-passage

I am a budding overlanding enthusiast planning to make a handful of international road trips from India in upcoming years. But I have seen that most people who travel to Europe or Central Asia take the Myanmar-China route which is much longer and troublesome due to stringent self-drive regulations of China. Why not take the route through Pakistan to reach central Asia or into Iran for Europe? If it's possible what will be the documents/paperworks required?

Comment: What country issued your passport? What country is your vehicle registered in? AFAIK Indian citizens and Indian registered vehicles are not allowed to drive across the border into Pakistan.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56621/is-it-possible-to-cross-the-wagan-border-by-car

Comment: India-India. Okay that answers my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to cross the border from Pakistan to Iran at the [Zahedan-Quetta border crossing](https://caravanistan.com/border-crossings/pakistan/zahedan-quetta/), which is also troublesome.

In Quetta, you will have to stay at the Bloomstar Hotel. You will not be allowed to leave until you get your NOC (Certificate of No Objection) certificate. The certificate is free, and you only need to have your passport with you.

At the border, you will also need your passport and visa. The website advises to take lots of copies, as you and your baggage will be checked lots of times.

Due to the fact that the process is not very organised, you will have to change escorts and be checked multiple times. The whole journey will take around 30 hours.